# react native. retrieve facebook login result on all screens

Tags: facebook-graph-api, react-native, facebook-login, react-native-fbsdk

I'm making a react native ios app with a facebook login and now needs to retrieve the result data on all other screens.

i'v got tree screens:

- Login.js
- Profile.js
- Main.js

Login contains the loginButton witch works and returns the users public_profile in the console.

Main contains a stacknavigator and imports the other screens

Profile is where I would like to print out the logged in users name, img ect.

The question is when onLoginFinished is a success it returns the user info in result, but how do I grab it on the other screens?

It looks like it's the GraphRequestManager and infoRequest I need, but can't figure out how to do it.

Main.js

```
'use-strict';
var React = require('react');
window.React = React;
import {AppRegistry, Text} from 'react-native';
import { StackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';

//login screen
import Login from './Login'

//profile screen
var Profile = require('./Profile.js');

const skatebayApp = StackNavigator({
  Login: {screen: Login},
  Profile: {screen: Profile},
},{
  headerMode: 'screen',
});

AppRegistry.registerComponent('skatebayApp', () => skatebayApp);
```

Login.js

```
'use-strict';
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  Text,
  View,
  TouchableHighlight,
  Image,
} from 'react-native';

const FBSDK = require('react-native-fbsdk');
const {
  LoginButton,
  AccessToken,
  GraphRequest,
  GraphRequestManager,
} = FBSDK;

export default class Login extends Component{

  render(){
    return(

    <LoginButton
      onLoginFinished={
        (error, result) => {
          if (error) {
            alert("login has error: " + result.error);
          } else if (result.isCancelled) {
            alert("login is cancelled.");
          } else {

            AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken().then((data) => {
              let accessToken = data.accessToken

              const responseInfoCallback = (error, result) => {
                if (error) {
                  console.log(error)
                  alert('Error fetching data: ' + error.toString());
                } else {
                  console.log(result)
                }
              }
              const infoRequest = new GraphRequest(
                '/me',
                {
                  accessToken: accessToken,
                    parameters: {
                      fields: {
                      string: 'email,name,first_name,last_name,picture'
                      }
                    }
                },
                responseInfoCallback,
                console.log(result)
              );
              new GraphRequestManager().addRequest(infoRequest).start()
            })
          }
        }
      } onLogoutFinished={() => console.log('signed out')}/>
  );
 }
}
```

Profile.js
- this is where i'd like to grab the the user info and print it out

```
'use-strict';
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  AppRegistry,
  Text,
  View,
  Image,
} from 'react-native';
import { StackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';


class Profile extends React.Component {

   render() {
   return (
      <View>
        <Text>Username & other info here</Text>
      </View>
   );
  }
}
module.exports = Profile;
```

Hope it makes any sense, i'm pretty new to react native.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store the user details in the asyncstorage after that you can access it from any screen. 
You can find more details here https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/asyncstorage.html

Comment: okay, so i would set the 'await AsyncStorage.setItem' in the const responseInfoCallback or in the 'const infoRequest'?

Comment: I am not familiar with graph api, just use this where you are printing the user details
 AsyncStorage.setItem('userData', JSON.stringify(userDetails));